# Is each conversion associated with an input/out format specifier a Sequence Point in C?

Tags: c, undefined-behavior, stdio, operator-precedence, sequence-points

Wikipedia entry on Sequence Points in C has this Sequence point:

> After each conversion associated with an input/output format
>   specifier. For example, in the expression printf("foo %n %d", &a, 42),
>   there is a sequence point after the %n is evaluated and before
>   printing 42

But C standard also says:

> The order of evaluation of the function designator, the actual
>   arguments, and subexpressions within the actual arguments is
>   unspecified, but there is a sequence point before the actual call.

These two points seems contradictory in nature for codes like this

```
int i=1;
printf("%d, %d and %d\n", i++, i++, i--);
```

According to wikipedia entry after each format specifier there is a sequence point so it will be printed like:
`1,2,3`

But according to unspecified beaviour entry in C standard, it can print anything.

Comment: What does it print for you?

Comment: can be 1,1,1 in output. in general result is undefined

Comment: @myradio Unless it prints “this is undefined behavior”, that doesn’t really answer the question in this case.

Comment: The `i++` example is undefined behaviour, not unspecified behaviour

Comment: @DanielH Mine was a question posted as a comment, never even attempted to answer the question. Nevertheless, depending on the output you might have a big hint of what's the actual behaviour.

Answer (score 6):

The Wikipedia page is poorly worded. The actual text is (C11 7.21.6):

> The formatted input/output functions shall behave as if there is a sequence point after the actions associated with each specifier.

These **actions** all occur *after* the sequence point described by your quote "there is a sequence point before the actual call".  The arguments and postfix-expression are evaluated; *then* the function is entered; *then* the actions specified by the format string occur in order.

The action associated with `%i` for example, is outputting the argument's value.  You seem to be mixing up "output the argument" with "evaluate the argument"; the latter occurs before the function is entered.

Answer (score 4):

Both the rules are correct. You are not reading them correctly.

First the second one -

> The order of evaluation of the function designator, the actual arguments, and subexpressions within the actual arguments is unspecified, but there is a sequence point before the actual call.

This means that the parameters to the function can be evaluated in any order. There is no sequence point between them.

Because of this a call like -

```
printf("%d, %d and %d\n", i++, i++, i--);
```

is not defined and invokes UB.

Now for the first one,

> After each conversion associated with an input/output format specifier. For example, in the expression printf("foo %n %d", &a, 42), there is a sequence point after the %n is evaluated and before printing 42

This is not talking about the parameter evaluation but the actual printing. Whenever each format specifier like `%d`, `%c`, `%n` is evaluated (both for `scanf` and `printf`) it could have side effects. These effects are sequenced in the order the format specifier appears in the string.

For instance

```
scanf("%d %d", &a, &b); // a and b are integers
```

The store to `a` will be sequenced before the store to `b`.

Similarly in case of `printf` as given in the example,

```
printf("foo %n %d", &a, 42);
```

The update to `a` will be sequenced before the printing of `42`.

There is no relation to how `42`, `&a`, `printf` or `"foo %n %d"` is evaluated.

Comment: If the example had been something like `printf("%42d%n%s", 0, &someInt, (char*)&someInt);` would the behavior be defined on a little-endian machine as outputting 41 blanks, a zero, and an asterisk (character code 42)?

Comment: @supercat, that is my understanding. Yes, it would be defined and the output would be what you said. Because there is a sequence point between the write to `someInt` and the read from `someInt`.

Answer (score 1):

The format string is an argument to the function and as such, that argument (the string) is evaluated before the function is called. There's no special magic here, but all parameters to `printf` are evaluated in an unspecified order, just as with any function. (Code such as `printf(ptr, ptr+n);` is therefore fishy and invokes poorly-specified behavior.)

Then before the function is called there is a sequence point.

Wikipedia says "there is a sequence point after the %n is evaluated and before printing 42". This is something else entirely. There's a special guarantee that the `%n` as part of the format string, is evaluated before the parameter corresponding to that specifier is printed. Formally this is specified in C11:

> 7.21.6 Formatted input/output functions
>
> The formatted input/output functions shall behave as if there is a sequence point after the actions associated with each specifier. 274)

This has nothing to do with the evaluation of the function arguments. So roughly, given this code:

```
printf("%d", i)
```

you'd have the following order of execution:

- `"%d"` and `i` are evaluated in an unspecified order before the function is called.
- Sequence point.
- The function is called.
- The string is parsed and the `%d` part is found and interpreted.
- Sequence point.
- `i` is printed.
- Sequence point.
- Function returns.

This special sequence point after format specifiers is apparently there because of the `%n` specifier specifically, which writes to memory according to a foot note:

> 274) The fprintf functions perform writes to memory for the %n specifier.